# Ajax post data while loop php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Sorry, I am a beginner.
I have some problem about ajax post data from while loop PHP.
Here is my code.

Assume that after while loop I have 5 records 5 buttons with different post data each record, but ajax will send only first data of record no matter I click which button in these 5 records ajax will send the same data of first record data

But, if I use $(this).val() ajax will send right data in each records.

Pls help. thx so much.

In PHP.

```
<?php while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($qr)) { ?>
        <td width="150">
             <input type="text" name="studentid" class="studentid" value="<?=$rs['studentid']?>"/>
      </td>
    <td width="100">
        <select name="ssize" class="ssize">
            <option value="">ไซต์</option>
            <option <?php if($rs['ssize'] == 'S') { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> value="S">S</option>
            <option <?php if($rs['ssize'] == 'M') { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> value="M">M</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <button value="<?=$rs['id']?>" class="printBill btn btn-primary">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate"> </i>
            พิมพ์ใบเสร็จ
    </button>
<?php } ?>
```

In JS.

```
$(".printBill").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
            url: "admin_search_save.php",
            data: {
                id:$(this).val(),
                studentid:$(".studentid").val(),
                ssize:$(".ssize").val(),
            },
            success: function (data) {
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: can you be a bit more specific with your question, like what exactly are you looking for

Comment: @Teerpong Phothiphun , can you post entire table stucture, then we can see where the elements located......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [**event delegation**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamically added content.

```
$(document).on('click','.printBill',function () {

        // capture input and select value by traversing up into parent(tr),
        // then find element [input, select]
        // this traversing method depend on your table structure
        var studID    = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name=studentid]').val(),
            ssizeData = $(this).closest('tr').find('select[name=ssize]').val();

        $.ajax({
        url: "admin_search_save.php",
        data: {
            id        : $(this).val(),
            studentid : studID,
            ssize     : ssizeData,
        },
        success: function (data) {
        }
    });
  });
```

Comment: They have multiple studentids and multiple ssizes. Can JavaScript pass all of them? There must be something more to handle.

Comment: @AkiEru : added the value of input and select. There is no need to send multiple value since the button itself was inside while loop, just need to capture the input and select element on the same row.